# Why is this lattice data missing?

Tags: curated-data, lattices, missing

Is there a reason why

```
LatticeData["FaceCenteredOrthorhombic", "Basis"]
```

returns

```
Missing["NotAvailable"]
```

while

```
LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", "Basis"]
```

returns, as I expect,

```
{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}}
```

?

I am aware that face-centered orthorhombic lattice is not one of the 14 Bravais lattices, but it still has its basis, doesn't it?